# Running Electron app causes ELIFECYCLE error

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, electron

I have a Vue.js app, running Electron. Here's a relevant part of my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
  "electron": "vue-cli-service build && electron ."
}
```

When I do `npm run serve`, the app works without any problems. However, when I do `npm run electron`, I receive this error message in my terminal:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! multimedia-index-app@0.1.0 electron: `vue-cli-service build && electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the multimedia-index-app@0.1.0 electron script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Following this, I get an alert:

[image]

The `electron.js` file is just boilerplate code that I copied from the official Electron website, so it's highly unlikely that it contains errors, much less syntax errors.

I have already tried the following, to no avail:

- `npm cache clean --force`
- delete `package-lock.json` file
- delete `node_modules` folder and `npm install`
- run VSCode as admin before running the electron script
- reinstall and update Electron and vue/cli

This app used to work fine. I came back to it after a month, and suddenly it doesn't. What other solutions can I try to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by renaming `electron.js` to `index.js`, and within this file - which, as I said, was just electron boilerplate - changing one line: `win.loadFile('index.html')` to `win.loadFile('dist/index.html')`. Obviously, I also updated any references to this file after changing its name.